# Como almacenar resultado de una funcion en una variable de postgresql

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

tengo esta funcion en Postgresql que me devuelve un codigo como resultado de su ejecucion. Dentro de esa funcion hay un insert a una tabla con un campo serial.

`SELECT generales.guardareditareliminarproductos(0,1,False,1,'JUGO ',2,3,3,2,1,False,3,1,1,'MSI',1,15);`

Quiero meter ese codigo dentro de una variable para usarlo en un nuevo insert

`INSERT INTO generales.tblpreciosproductos(producto,moneda,precio,empresa,uposteo,fposteo,pc)`

`Select @ResultadoFuncion,1,10,1,1,current_timestamp,'MSI';`

Algo parecido a lo de arriba, que dentro de esa variable @ResultadoFuncion este el resultado de mi función y poder insertarlo en esa nueva tabla.

Muchas Gracias de Antemano
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de si es lo que buscas, pero para guardar el resultado de un `SELECT` en una tabla hay que usar [SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html):

Un ejemplo (esta función retornará un valor booleano dándole el nombre de una tabla):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION existe(
    _nombretabla character varying
    )
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE    
resultado boolean;    
BEGIN
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM _nombretabla WHERE "algunacondicion") INTO resultado
RETURN resultado;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: Lo que me gustaría es almacenar ese resultado boleano que retorna la función en una variable para otros propósitos. En mi caso quiero retornar el código de resultado de mi función y guardarlo en una variable.